# Can you delay AJAX requests (for month change) in jQuery FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using [jquery fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) which works great. The one issue I have is if you click forward or backward to move through multiple months very quickly, it still tries to fire off multiple ajax requests and it doesn't wait to see if you actually "settle" down on that month.

I basically want it to wait for 1 second before it fires off an ajax event to make sure the user isn't going to click next again.

Is this possible in jquery full calendar?  I would have thought a plugin with such following and other advanced features would have this

Comment: It doesn't look like it. [`fetchEvents`](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/EventManager.js) could be monkey-patched, but ... sorta icky. Time to get your hands dirty :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got it, basically putting a timer inside the events call back and throttle from there.

I thought of doing something like this:

```
 events: function (start, end, callback) {

        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }

        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            put loadMonthData call here;
            callback here();
        }, 1000);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

JQuery has a whole range of Ajax event handlers like [ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/), [ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) and [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/).

Using the ajaxPrefilter() method you could probably capture the Ajax request before it's sent, delay it and if a click event on the month navigator buttons isn't detected within the timeframe send the request, otherwise abort it.

This is a bit of a contrived example, but something along these lines might be close to what you want:

```
var enableRequest = true;

$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
  // Modify options, control originalOptions, store jqXHR, etc

    if (!enableRequest ){
        jqXHR.abort();
    }
});

$('span.fc-button-prev, span.fc-button-next').click(function(){
    enableRequest = false;
    setTimeout("setEnabled()", 2000)
});


function setEnabled()
{
    enableRequest = true;
});
```

Comment: I can't sort this one out, but this answer seems to have a lot of potential. Here is a fiddle that includes a calendar as well as a binding to the month change click events. I've put in the code to check whether clicks have been within one second. Perhaps you can extend it to make use of ajaxPrefilter to halt the request? http://jsfiddle.net/JfC6z/

Comment: this is promising . . but you are never actually firing off the ajax after the one second (just setting a flag to be true)

Comment: I have updated the questions with some more progress but i am still stuck on the callback() that needs to exist inside the events function

Comment: I got it working but i upvoted your answer as that (along with mrtsherman) definately help fiture it out.

Comment: Fantastic. Do you have a jsFiddle of your eventual solution?

Answer (score -1):

Could you try editing fullcalendar.js ?

~ line 114

```
var fc = $.fullCalendar = { version: "1.5.3" };
var fcViews = fc.views = {};
var ajax = null; // Add this line
```

~ line 978

```
pushLoading();
if (ajax) // add this line
    ajax.abort(); // add this line
    ajax = $.ajax($.extend({}, ajaxDefaults, source, { // CHange this line
                data: data,
                success: function(events) {
                    ajax = null; // Add this line
                    events = events || [];
                    var res = applyAll(success, this, arguments);
                    if ($.isArray(res)) {
                        events = res;
                    }
                    callback(events);
                },
```

That way it should stop any "double ajax query", i think.

Comment: i can see how this sorts of works around the issue but it still seems like a cleaner solution is to avoid any ajax calls at all until you are "settled" down on a page and not still clicking . .